# Why don't these threads run in sequence?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I have difficulty understanding `synchronized` and reentrant lock. Here is small program I was experimenting with:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Reentr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService eService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            eService.execute(new process());
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        eService.shutdown();
    }

}

class process implements Runnable {
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        processTest();
    }

    public synchronized void processTest() {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                count += i;
                System.out.println("count value for " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is " + count);
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("count for " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is " + count);
        }
    }

}
```

The output was:

```
count value for pool-1-thread-2 is 1
count value for pool-1-thread-1 is 1
count value for pool-1-thread-2 is 3
count for pool-1-thread-2 is 3
count value for pool-1-thread-1 is 3
count for pool-1-thread-1 is 3
```

If we see in the output two thread are in the synchronized block. I was under the impression that one thread has to complete the execution of synchronized method, after that other thread will enter the method.

Ideally, I was expecting result something like this

```
count value for pool-1-thread-1 is 1
count value for pool-1-thread-1 is 3
count for pool-1-thread-1 is 3
count value for pool-1-thread-2 is 1
count value for pool-1-thread-2 is 3
count for pool-1-thread-2 is 3
```

I have replaced synchronized method with synchronized block and re-entrant locks. However, I still have the same output. What am I missing?

Comment: You have new instances of ``process`` each time. There's no contention for their critical sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The two threads are not synchonizing on the same object.

You have two different instances of `process` (as an aside; you should always name classes with a Capital letter). The `synchronized` keyword is equivalent to:

```
public void processTest() {
  synchronized(this) {
    // etc..
  }
}
```

If you want one thread to run after the other, they must synchronize on the same object. If you did this, for example:

```
class process implements Runnable {
  // note that this is static
  private static final Object lock = new Object();

  public void processTest() {
    synchronized(lock) {
      // your code
    }
  }
}
```

Then your code would have one thread run after the other. Another way to do it would be to pass the lock into the `Object`s constructor, or the same instance of a `Semaphore`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reponse .. i missed that i was creating new object every time

Answer (score 1):

When an instance method is declared `synchronized`, it synchronizes on the object instance.  Since you are running with a `new process()` in each loop iteration, the object instances are different, so the synchronization is meaningless.  Try creating a single `process` object and passing that to both of the threads you start.

When you do, also move the `count` instance variable into the `processTest` method.  That way it will be thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for response .. i missed that i was creating new object every time